# Root of a quadratic equation that has modulus $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, roots

Let us suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ and $|\alpha|=1$ and $\alpha$ satisfies a monic quadratic equation. Then prove that $\alpha^{12} =1$.

Show me the right way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha$ a matrix?

Comment: What type of number is $\alpha$?  In the reals, your conditions imply $\alpha=1$, so proving $\alpha^{12}=1$ is not hard.  In the complex numbers, what $\gt$ are you using?

Comment: Are you familiar with [cyclotomic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see $\alpha>0$. What does it mean? Is it the main reason of downvotes?

Comment: @Landscape I can only assume that the downvotes are because this is posed as an isolated question with no indication of research or an attempt to solve on the OP's part, and thanks to the current moderator election and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9330/should-problem-statement-questions-be-an-issue-for-the-election) meta thread (among others), the action we should take against such "problem statement questions" has become a major topic in the community (action is a strong word, but I think it's suitable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha\in \bf C$ is a root of some quadratic polynomial $x^2+ax+b\in{\bf Q}[x]$ and $|\alpha|=1$.

Then $\displaystyle\alpha=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$. If $\alpha\ne\pm1$ then $a^2<4b$, and

$$1=\alpha\overline{\alpha}=\frac{a^2-(a^2-4b)}{4}=b,\quad -2<a<+2.$$

It is false that $\alpha$ must be a $12$th root of unity; check either root of e.g. $x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+1$. However if we restrict $a,b\in\bf Z$ to be integers, then $-2<a<2\iff a\in\{-1,0,+1\}$, and it can be checked that

- the values $\alpha=\pm1$ are second roots of unity,
- roots of $x^2+1$ are primitive fourth roots of unity, $\pm i$,
- roots of $x^2-x+1$ are primitive sixth roots of unity,
- roots of $x^2+x+1$ are primitive cube roots of unity,

and all of the above are twelfth roots of unity. However, observe that none of these is a *primitive* twelfth root; the possible values for $\alpha$ are precisely the nonprimitive twelfth roots of unity.

The last two bullet points above are covered in the theory of cyclotomic polynomials, as the two polynomials listed are in fact $\Phi_6(x)$ and $\Phi_3(x)$.

- If $x^2+x+1=0$ then multiply by $x-1$ to obtain the relation $x^3-1=0$, but $x=1$ is impossible so $x$ must be a primitive cube root.
- If $x^2-x+1=0$ then multiply by $(x^2+x+1)(x^2-1)$ to obtain $x^6-1=0$, but $x$ cannot be a root of $x^2-1$ or of $x^2+x+1$ at the same time, so it is not a second or third root of unity while it is a sixth root, hence it is a primitive sixth root of unity.

Comment: this the exact answer which I want...nice answer..@anon